# export 'ethers'.'providers' (imported as 'ethers') was not found in 'ethers'

Tags: ether, react

I am trying to build a very basic React frontend for my NFT contract. This is my app.js:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import './App.css';
import contract from './Contracts/NFTCollectible.json';
const contractAddress = "0x0024786Eb4E2FF93b17C22EddeA2573F883FEb8d";
const abi = contract.abi;

function App() {
const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState(null);


  const checkWalletIsConnected = async () => {
const { ethereum } = window;


if(!ethereum){
    console.log("Clearly, a wallet is needed.")
    return;
}
else{
    console.log("Yay! You're all set up!")
}

const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts'});

if(accounts.length !== 0){
    const account = accounts[0];
    console.log("Found an authroized account:", account);
    setCurrentAccount(account); 
}else{
    console.log("No authorised account found!");
}
      }

  const connectWalletHandler = async () => { 
  const { ethereum } = window;
  
  if(!ethereum)
  {
      alert("Please install Metamsk!");
  }
  try {
      
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      console.log("Found an account! Address: ", accounts[0]);
      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
     } catch(err){
         console.log(err)
     }
  
  }

  const mintNftHandler = async () => { 
  try {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      
      if (ethereum){
          const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
          const signer = provider.getSigner();
          const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
          
          console.log("Initialize payment!");
          let nftTxn = await nftContract.mintNFTs(1, { value: ethers.parseEther("0.01") });
          
          console.log("Mining... please wait!");
          await nftTxn.wait();
          
          console.log(`Mined, see transaction https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/${nftTxn.hash}`);
          
      }else{
          console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist.");
      }
     
      

      
  }
  catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }

  
  }

  const connectWalletButton = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={connectWalletHandler} className='cta-button connect-wallet-button'>
        Connect Wallet (No scam)
      </button>
    )
  }

  const mintNftButton = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={mintNftHandler} className='cta-button mint-nft-button'>
        Mint NFT (Again, no scam)
      </button>
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkWalletIsConnected();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='main-app'>
      <h1>Bored Bits</h1>
      <div>
        {currentAccount ? mintNftButton() : connectWalletButton()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

My issue is with the 3rd line, to do with importing ethers. I have already tried downgrading my version, but I get the same issue. I think that they have had an update, where the syntax looks like this:

`````
 ````const { ethers } = require("ethers");````
`````

But when I do that, I get many more errors, I think because Ether isn't imported.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using ethers v6

```
import { BrowserProvider } from "ethers";
```

then in `useEffect` set the provider state

```
 const [provider, setProvider] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const browserProvider = new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    setProvider(browserProvider);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed part of it. I'm now getting the error: `'ethers' is not defined  no-undef` I've read that putting in this line: `const { ethers } = require("hardhat");` should fix it, but when I do it,  I get many errors that `Cannot find module 'path'`. Thanks!